# Load Data into S3 with Informatica powercenter

Tags: amazon-s3, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I'm working on project in order to load data into Amazon S3 file (file target imported with AmazonS3 plugin) with informatica powercenter using Amazon_s3 connector, but the problème is when i execute the workflow it fails (it never have been succeeded till now)

the error is the directory can't be created even so i have the rights of creating and writing in the folder Temp.

```
 Message Code: Amazon_S3 Writer_30031
Message: [ERROR] File has not been created in the specified directory: [F:\DEV0PWC\PWC\Temp\InfaS3Staging0006041652299037943744_0]
Message Code: GENERIC_WRITER_5
Message: [ERROR] Error while initializing the writer : [Failed to create the file in the specified location F:\DEV0PWC\PWC\Temp\InfaS3Staging11060412211690186912208_0:The system cannot find the path specified]
Message Code: JAVA PLUGIN_1762
Message: [ERROR] com.informatica.powercenter.sdk.SDKException: com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.InitializationException: Failed to create the file in the specified location F:\DEV0PWC\PWC\Temp\InfaS3Staging11060412211690186912208_0:The system cannot find the path specified
    at com.informatica.cloud.adapter.amazons3.write.AmazonS3Write.initializeAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.WriterWrapper.initializeAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.writer.runtime.GenericWriterPartitionDriver.init(Unknown Source)
```

Have you any informations about this please !

Comment: I am assuming that you have this process that used to work but not not working. 1. can you pls check if the file system is reachable from Informatica ? Login using infa user and see if you can reach `F:\DEV0PWC\PWC\Temp\`. 2. I am assuming you are using windows PC server, see that mapping to `F:\DEV0PWC\PWC\Temp\` is correct or not or not lost recently. 3. AWS access/path/password/endpoint etc. can change periodically - check if you have all settled.

Comment: thank @KoushikRoy for your reply, yes i checked what you said it work perfectly i cant reach temp with the user Informatica, for AWS we have two keys wich are secret and access key for the user informatica and they work fine ( i can import source/target from Amazon S3 with Amazon S3plugin in designer), also the bucket privacy have all the rights, i can't see the source of the problem.

Comment: I can* reach the temp

Comment: you can setup verbose in session and see if any details popped up. also, if you say you can reach s3, can you please check if you can write in it.